# How to uninstall the Hadoop on Mac Completely

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have installed hadoop 2.5.1 on my mac book pro through terminal but now i want to uninstall completely from my mac book pr.

so please let me know the process.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you installed it through repo or tarball?

Comment: i have install through tarball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed by downloading and extracting Hadoop tarball, then you just have to delete the extracted directory (the directory path depends on where you have extracted the tarball to on the filesystem) using command line utility like [rm](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rm.1.html).

Also, if you have changed Namenode, Datanode data directories (by configuring them in `hdfs-site.xml`) other than the default then you have to delete those directories as well.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Where is the extracted directory?

Comment: It may be installed in this location: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop. Hope this helps.